# How to automatically create DynamoDB table on application startup using Spring Data DynamoDB?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am using [spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb)  Spring Data extension to integrate AWS DynamDB with Spring Boot 2.0. I was able to make it work.

My question is, is there a way that the table is automatically created on application startup if it doesn't already exists, similar to what Hiberate offers via `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` ?. Right now, I have to create the table manually or in the application using the AWS DynamoDB sdk. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Right now there is no such feature but there is an open feature request: https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/17 (which I'm actually working on these days)

Note: I'm the maintainer of this GitHub project.

Comment: this is working now as of 5.1.0
https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Autocreate-Tables