# DynamoDB in SpringBoot yml configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do auto creation tables in a local Dynamo DB. The problem is when I type these lines in the .yml configuration I am getting "Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.data.dynamodb.entity2ddl.auto'" and the auto is highlited.

Application.yml file

```
spring:
  data:
    dynamodb:
      entity2ddl:
        auto: create-drop
```

In the pom.xml file I have these dependencies for aws:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.857</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have searched a little and based on the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51157179/7189597

and the following Github repository:

https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Autocreate-Tables

It is now available by using these properties in your property file:

```
spring.data.dynamodb.entity2ddl.auto = none
spring.data.dynamodb.entity2ddl.gsiProjectionType = ALL
spring.data.dynamodb.entity2ddl.readCapacity = 10
spring.data.dynamodb.entity2ddl.writeCapacity = 1
```

Also, other values are:

`create-only`, `drop`, `create-drop`, `create`, `validate`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that and I am getting a similar error
"Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.data.dynamodb.entity2ddl.writeCapacity'"

Comment: @some0neninja take a look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671309/7189597 , maybe it a version mismatch issue